# Ошибка с библиотекой web3 и методом getBalance

Tags: python, python-3.x, ethereum, криптовалюта

```
from web3 import eth
k='0xd4FD252d7D2C9479a8d616F510eAC6243B5DDdf9'
balance = eth.Eth.getBalance(k)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    balance = eth.Eth.getBalance(k)
TypeError: getBalance() missing 1 required positional argument: 'account'
```

Comment: Попробуйте создать экземпляр `Web3` с именем `w3` и вызвать `w3.eth.getBalance(k)`

Comment: @dIm0n Сделал так:
`from web3 import Web3`
`w3 = Web3()`
`balance = w3.eth.getBalance(k)`
Ошибка очень длинная получилась, но вот ее конец:
`web3.exceptions.CannotHandleRequest: Could not discover provider while making request: method:eth_getBalance
params:['0xd4FD252d7D2C9479a8d616F510eAC6243B5DDdf9', 'latest']`

Comment: Подозреваю, что для `Web3` нужны какие-то аргументы. Это читали https://stackoverflow.com/q/48181275/13970074?

Comment: @dIm0n Как то все очень запутано. Не понимаю как это связано. Может вы знаете какой то вариант, как можно проще узнать баланс eth кошелька по адресу?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению, не знаю. Просто поискал по ошибке вашей, везде говорят, что надо сначала создать экземпляр `Web3`